# Dynamically calling methods

Tags: java

In PHP we can call methods dynamically like this:

```
class Klass{
    function method1(){ ... }
    function method2(){ ... }
    function method3(){ ... }

    function methodN(){ ... }
}
```

And I can call dynamically like this:

```
Klass k = new Klass();
$i = 0;
while($i <= N){
    k->method{$i}();
}

//or
$i = 'anything';    
k->$i();
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I achieve this in JAVA?

Comment: Make use of reflection api

Comment: Without reflection, you can't.